# In Aurelia.js, how do I make supporting html for routers load on demand rather than startup?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, url-routing, aurelia

In Aurelia.js, if you look at network traffic, it seems that all html pages for the routers are loaded at start-time (loaded by system.js since I am bundling). This makes my page load slower. I need them to load on demand, like when a router corresponding hyperlink is clicked.

Comment: As a workaround, does your server gzips the responses? If not, it's the easiest way to see an increase in speed.

Comment: @MikeSW I wrote up ways I used to speed up the app, and added some clarification. For some unknown reason, someone gave the question and my answer a negative vote and no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting idea. I'm not a core team member so maybe someone with deep knowledge of the router can comment on the ability to do what you're asking. I know what I'm about to say below doesn't directly answer your question, but I'm providing it as-is in case it's still helpful.

Generally, most people "bundle" their app before deploying to production.  See https://github.com/aurelia/bundler for an example on how to do this in Aurelia.  The Aurelia Skeleton app has this build pipeline wired in as well by default (https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation).

Bundling reduces the number of network requests, but it still loads the entire app at once. You have to think of SPA apps more like desktop apps.  The HTML template or "view" template you edit is actually compiled into JavaScript, then combined with the data it needs by your "view model". 
One approach that results in smaller downloads is to break up a large monolithic application into several smaller applications. You create separate Aurelia apps that are loaded at different server URLs. You then have a mixture of server routing (to route users between applications) and client routing (to route a user within an application). This obviously creates complexity in your development lifecycle though.

Comment: Bundling reduces the load-time but its still large. Breaking up a small app to different separate apps is not a good option (makes it even more complex). Still, thanks for looking at this question. If there is a good answer, I see SPA (using HTML5's compose and template tags and with aurelia.js) even further reducing the need to build multi-page app in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Several things occurred.

- The question may be a bit confusing. The routers are not calling the resources; they are just consuming them. Also, its about start-up speed. That has to be clear.
- Ensure bundling is done correct- copy over config file to deployment server, ensure you are bundling all necessary files, etc (mines was not). You can gain tremendous increase in start-up time if bundling is done correctly. Look at the developer tools and watch for anything suspicious.
- If you still have trouble with a large app, you may experiment with having multiple bundles. See the Aurelia's documentation on bundling.
- This is beta 1. There should be some performance enhancement coming in beta 2 and release #1. So far, in Beta 1, for the same browser, it seems that linux is way faster than Windows in regards to start-up time. IE and Edge are slower than other browsers when using aurelia.
- This may help allieviate some of the problem. Added async attribute on external script calls (depending on needs, defer may work too.) Also added "lazyload" attributes on img-tag. It only works in IE and Edge, but its help since IE and Edge are the slowest browsers in many cases.